TypeScript Interface Method Not Recognized in Vue Component
I’m working with TypeScript and Vue.js. I’ve created a TypeScript class that implements an interface, and I’ve defined a public method in the abstract class what is my class extending. However, when I try to call this method from within a Vue component, TypeScript throws this error :
Property 'validateFormAttributeValues' does not exist on type '{ getId: () => string | null; getFirstName: () => string | null; setFirstName: (name: string) => void; getLastName: () => string | null; setLastName: (name: string) => void; getEmail: () => string | null; ... 10 more ...; setContactDateTime: (contactDateTime: ProbandContactDateTime | null) => void; }'.ts(2339)
Even though it’s declared as public. What could be causing this issue?
Here’s a simplified version of my code:

export default abstract class FormModel 
implements FormComponentInterface
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.setValidationSchema();
    }

    setValidationSchema(): void
    {
        throw new Error("setValidationSchema not implemented")
    }
   
    validateFormAttributeValues()
    {
        // call service for validation
        ValidationService.validateFormComponent(this);
        
        return true;
    }   
}

export default class BaseProband 
extends AbstractFormModel
implements BaseProbandInterface


//draftModel is declared like this
draftModel: BaseProbandInterface | null //| FormModel

I also tried to declare it directly as FormModel.

Please, provide stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem . It's unclear how it looks in whole. There are commented FormModel, it's unclear if the problem persists with them uncommented or not. There is no object with "getFirstName", etc properties in the code you posted
